# IEnumerable or DataTable for Updates

Tags: c#, datatable, ienumerable

I understand this may be somewhat remedial but I am trying to decide if I am wasting resources converting an `IEnumerable` to a DataTable. I have the data in `IEnumerable<T>` but I need to apply business logic. I will have Data in another `IEnumerable<T>` that I will be comparing against and other such business operations. It seems to me that I should be able to do anything to the strongly typed enumerable objects same as a DataTable.....but I am more familiar with DataTables so unsure of myself.

In the end the data will end up in a `List<T>` and be serialized by a web service so I really feel as though going to and from a dataset is a waste?

Am I correct in thinking I can do anything to the `IEnumerable` objects same as a `DataTable`? If I am to use the IEnumerables should I simply have helper methods that do "the work" or should I go the extra mile and create extensions?

---

My green newbie is showing. Let me give you a little more information about the data and how it is used. The data will be personal information going to a subscriber. They may makes changes and then send the update back.

The data is rolled up and sent to them but it is stored in a normalized (3rd level I think it is) state. I roll up the data using SP's and UDF's etc. The process has alot of join's and a cursor to evaluate historical records the user has submitted about themselves to then determine the recommended action. The user may take the recommended action or not but whatever they do it is sent back and broken down back into it's normalized state for the next time.

The debate I am running (test environ so no harm) is to replace the db operations with an ORM and execute the business logic via workflow in the middle tier. This will allow me to be more dynamic and fluid with business changes. My ORM gets my data but it is in an IEnumerable form and thus I am looking for the best data structure for my workflow to execute against. In the end I am not binding to anything but creating a custom object that gets serialized and sent to the client via web service.

Please if I can provide more information don't hesitate. I'm not trying to be obtuse.
Thank You

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is not indexable, so not everything can be done on one in the same manner. For us to tell you the best data structure to use, you probably need to tell us what you are doing with the data and how you need to access it. It seems strange to me you are using a DataTable just to manipulate data. A shot in the dark, I'd say just try a List<T> instead.. but again we need to know what you are doing

Comment: Between linq and even simple List<T> management, I think there is no need to go to DataTables for data manipulation. As stated, If you tell us what you want to do to the data we might be more helpful. Reminder - DataTable was first designed in order to simplify database access not for data manipulation.

Comment: Eyal I was off on another project then the holidays but I am back now and your comment was my solution. I cast the object into a List<T> using the ToList extension method then use LINQ to do whatever I need. I'd like to give you the credit so if you could convert your comment to an answer I';ll be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` is mostly a readonly API. You have access to all members, you can work with them further, but you cannot add new or delete some. `ReadOnly` is the "second" name.

`DataTable` on the other hand is more related to ADO.NET, it is definitely not good solution for DTO nor business objects. It supports adding, deleting and removing, but should be used only on data layer.

I would suggest use the Facade pattern on your business layer, wrapping validations calls while internally working with Dao or Repositary

Answer (score 0):

[Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) could be used to perform any requests/transformations on this `IEnumerable<T>`. You probably don't need DataTables at all. The available LINQ extension methods could be chained/combined in other custom extension methods that you could write.

As far as Updates are concerned, you could put this IEnumerable into an indexable collection if you want to more easily access individual items by index. But that will depend on the exact operations you are willing to perform.